# Is it possible to configure autoscaling for Service Fabric guest executable and Service Fabric containers?

Tags: containers, azure-service-fabric, guest-executable

I read that SF services support autoscaling but couldn't find anything about autoscaling in SF guest executable and SF container.
Does anyone have information about it? 
Did anyone try to do it and can explain the steps?

Thanks!

Comment: For Application level (and not just the node)

Comment: Are you talking about onPrem or in Azure?